# Model associations not working Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations

Here are my associations:

- As user has many projects
- A project belongs to one user

User model (user.rb)

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :projects
     attr_accessible: :available, :department, :name, :skills, :title, :photo
  end
```

Project modal (project.rb)

```
  class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => :user_id
     attr_accessible :project_name
  end
```

Here's the code in my show.erb.html file

```
  <%= @user.projects.each do |project| %>
    <p><%= projects.project_name %></p>
  <% end %>
```

But this just displays two brackets like this "[]". Which makes me think it's an empty array.

So when I run `Project.find(1)` in rails console to see if the project is being associated with the user, it spits out this:

```
   => #<Project id: 2, project_name: "This is a project. ", created_at: "2012-11-12 02:29:28", updated_at: "2012-11-12 02:29:28", user_id: nil>
```

User id nil? What gives?!

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Here is the migration adding the foreign key:

```
  class AddForeignKeyToProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      add_column :projects, :user_id, :integer
    end
  end
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is the instances in the controllers (this is probably the problem)

Project controller

```
  def new
    @project = Project.new(params[:project], params[:user_id])   
  end
```

User controller

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id], params[:project_name])

    respond_to do |format|
       format.html # show.html.erb
       format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Where is the code showing how you assigned the project to a user?

Comment: Are you referring to the associations? They are in the models.

Comment: I'm referring to that specific project. When u defined that project you should have said project.user = User.find(1) or something like that. Did you do that?

Comment: Post your migrations please.

Comment: You need to show us how you are creating the Project instance, so we can help you figure out why the user_id attribute is not getting assigned.

Comment: Ok I added the controllers. See edit 2. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used convention name, it means you had a `user_id` in **Project** table, you don't need to specify `foreign_key` in **Project** model, you just need:

```
belongs_to :user
```

I don't sure if this is your typo:

```
<%= projects.project_name %> should be <%= project.project_name %>
```

About your controller, I suppose you have `current_user` method, which define current user logged in. So if you want to create new project with `user_id` associated with current_user's id, you should write this code:

```
def new
  @project = current_user.projects.build # Create new project with user_id = current_user.id
end
```

If you want to create new project, your `create` action will like this:

```
def create
  @project = current_user.projects.create(params[:project])

  if @project.save # save project success
    # do some thing
  else
    # do some thing
  end
end
```

Those are basic actions I can show you, because I don't know how you build form, and how your route look like.

When you show a user, if you used RESTful routes, your route will look like this:

```
`abc.com/users/:id/show`
```

What is RESTful routes? If you want to know you should check this [Recource routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default).

Then, if you want to find a user, you could use `params[:id]`:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @user }
  end
end
```

You can not find a user with `params[:project_name]`, your user model don't have that attribute, it's attribute of project.

Comment: Wow didn't even think to use current.user. That helped me out so much!!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

In the iteration `project` is your target not `projects`

```
<%= @user.projects.each do |project| %>
  <p><%= project.project_name %></p>
<% end %>
```

---Here is example of what i mean by assigning project to a user---
---In this code i user donations and members, same idea though---

```
donation = Donation.new(amount: random_value.to_c,
                          date_given: Random.date(1000).to_date,
                          donation_type: ['tithes', 'offering', 'undisclosed', 'building-fund'].sample)
  member = Member.all.sample
  donation.member= member
  donation.save
```

Comment: This didn't do it. The user_id for the project is still returning as nil.